# What does the argument 'weak' or 'strong' do for scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components?

Tags: python, numpy, graph, scipy, graph-algorithm

The below code demonstrates that the directed graph:

```
Nodes: 0, 1, 2
Edges: [0 -> 1], [2 -> 1]
```

is considered to be one weakly connected component, and three strongly connected components.

```
assert(scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components(np.array([[0,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,1,0]]), directed=True, connection='weak', return_labels=True) == (1, array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)))

assert(scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components(np.array([[0,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,1,0]]), directed=True, connection='strong', return_labels=True) == (3, array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int32)))
```

I understand why the strongly connected component return value makes sense -- I cannot traverse from 0 to 2, nor from 1 to 0 or from 1 to 2.

But according to the docs:

```
directedbool, optional
    If True (default), then operate on a directed graph: only move
    from point i to point j along paths csgraph[i, j]. If False,
    then find the shortest path on an undirected graph: the
    algorithm can progress from point i to j along csgraph[i, j]
    or csgraph[j, i].

connectionstr, optional    
    [‘weak’|’strong’]. For directed graphs, the type of connection
    to use. Nodes i and j are strongly connected if a path exists
    both from i to j and from j to i. Nodes i and j are weakly
    connected if only one of these paths exists. If directed ==
    False, this keyword is not referenced.
```

The 'weak' connected component should not exist, because 2 is not reachable by 1 nor 1 reachable by 2.

What's going on here? Is the documentation correct?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is incorrect and will be updated in a future version of Scipy. See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9861

The future documentation will read:

```
connection : str, optional
    ['weak'|'strong'].  For directed graphs, the type of connection to
    use.  Nodes i and j are strongly connected if a path exists both
    from i to j and from j to i. A directed graph is weakly connected
    if replacing all of its directed edges with undirected edges produces
    a connected (undirected) graph. If directed == False, this keyword
    is not referenced.
```

which is a standard definition for weakly connected.